# If two PSDs are related, are the PDFs of the time-series related?

Tags: statistics, signal-processing, fast-fourier-transform

Suppose a power spectral density (PSD) is related to another PSD by a function $\alpha(\omega)$. $$S_a(\omega) = \alpha(\omega)S_b(\omega)$$
If we generate an ensemble of time-series $x_a(t), x_b(t)$ from each of these PSDs, using the inverse Fourier transform (rather IFFT) with randomized phases, will the probability density function(PDF) (or Cumulative distribution function(CDF)) of the two be related,$$P(x_a(t)) = H\times P(x_b(t))$$ for some condition on $\alpha(\omega)$. Can this be shown analytically/ semi-analytically?

Comment: Not clear for me. The inverse transform of the PSD is an autocorrelation function (which is not random). You ask about the PDF... of what? Please elaborate

Comment: I've edited it a bit. PDF of the signal in time, for all the generated signals. Let's say x(t) is voltage. We have n possible voltage signals. PDF of the voltage for all these functions taken together.

Comment: @newtonian The power spectral density provides only a partial description of the statistics of a random process. Even if it holds $S_a(\omega)=S_b(\omega)$ you cannot conclude anything else about the statistics (and possible relation) of $x_a(t)$, $x_b(t)$.

Answer (score 1):

See section 8.2 in [this book](http://hajek.ece.illinois.edu/ECE534Notes.html).

$S_a$ is the cross-power spectral density of filtering a wide sense stationary process with power spectral density through a linear time invariant filter with transfer function  $\alpha(w)$ (for appropriate $\alpha$).

Note that the PSD is only a second moment characterization of a random process -- the PSD doesn't capture higher order information (e.g. what the third moments of $x_a$ or $x_b$ are), so $H$ cannot be uniquely determined in general (in fact, you don't even know what the distribution of $x_a$ is, just given the power spectral densities) but if the process $x_a$ is Gaussian+WSS, $x_b$ will be jointly Gaussian with $x_a$ and you have a complete characterization of what $H$ is provided you know what the mean of $x_a$ is).

Comment: Thank you. I understand that _H_ cannot be uniquely determined in general. But can we at least say that the shape of the two CDFs will be the same? Ie. They belong to the same distribution type with the same shape parameter?

Comment: No. You only have second moment information -- the third moments or higher can be vastly different. If you assume the input is Gaussian, you'l have Gaussian output if you filter it through a linear system. For more than that, you might be able to get some properties like you want if you look at stable distributions under appropriate conditions (see Signal processing with alpha-stable distributions and applications by Nikias and Shao or similar).